# Trigger JS Function form outside a IFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an iframe that loads in content... in there is a hyperlink that I want to add. In the holding page that contains the iframe is a js function. How could I trigger that function from within the iframe... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your broad question, try something like:

```
parent.yourfunction();
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
parent.foo();
```

or

```
top.foo();
```